# i have a issue in view job button in Django Project

Tags: python, django, button

I am new in Django and I am trying to do my project and I have an issue in that project. in my project, I have a view job button and whenever I click on any job or view job then it will redirect to another page and on that page, I want to show a full description of that job so please help me. thank you.

this is my views.py

```
def BrowseJob(request):
all_job = jobs.objects.all()
myFilter = jobsFilter(request.GET, queryset = all_job)
all_job = myFilter.qs
return render(request,'jobs.html',{'all_job':all_job,'myFilter':myFilter})
```

this is urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [path('',views.index,name='index'),
            path('Browse_Job',views.BrowseJob,name='Browse_Job'),
            path('contact',views.contact,name='contact'),
            path('job_details',views.jobdetails,name="job_details")]
```

this is my job.html

```
{% for job in all_job %}
            <div class="job_lists">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="single_jobs white-bg d-flex justify-content-between">
                            <div class="jobs_left d-flex align-items-center">
                                <div class="thumb">
                                    <img src="{{job.job_img.url}}" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="jobs_conetent">
                                    <a href="job_details"><h4>{{job.job_name}}</h4></a>
                                    <div class="links_locat d-flex align-items-center">
                                        <div class="location">
                                            <p> <i></i>{{job.job_Category}}</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="location">
                                            <p> <i></i>{{job.job_Experience}}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="jobs_right">
                                <div class="apply_now">
                                    <a href="job_details" class="boxed-btn3">View Job</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="date">
                                    <p>Last Date for Apply: {{job.last_date}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

this is my jobdetails.html

```
{% for job in all_job %}
  <img src="{{job.job_details.url}}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

please help me.

Comment: Add details of current behaviour and if u see any error

Answer (score 0):

Actually to redirect in django using names in urls.py you need to write 'href' like this
`<a href="{% url 'job_details' %}"><h4>{{job.job_name}}</h4></a>`

Instead of

`<a href="job_details"><h4>{{job.job_name}}</h4></a>`

then it will work as you expected
refer this for more details :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/